# Distribution-independent way of testing if an interface's current IP was obtained via DHCP?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

Firstly, parsing configuration files isn't really correct. And not nearly distro-independent either.

My first idea was to search for running dhclient processes, but each distribution uses a different esoteric command line. Even the binary name itself varies. In Fedora, it's dhclient. In Ubuntu, it's dhclient3.

Is there something in /proc or /sys that indicates that an IP is dynamic?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you grepped around in `/var/lib/dhcp*/dh*lease*` ?

Comment: @Dennis: That looks good. I'm using it.

Comment: @Juliano: remote system info gathering.

Comment: For the record: there are other DHCP clients one could be using (dhcpcd etc.) so looking for dhclient processes is really not a proper way to go about it. (But you probably suspected as much)

Comment: Yes, for instance, pump is a very good alternative to dhclient.

Comment: What distros out there use pump? Including non-Linux ones like *BSD and OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you grepped around in `/var/lib/dhcp*/dh*lease*` ?

On my Ubuntu system, as an example, `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient-eth0.lease` contains information about the current and recent leases.

Comment: -1 because it is dhclient-specific and there are other DHCP clients.

Comment: The OP specified dhclient and dhclient3 in the question.

Comment: So, how do pump and others store the leases?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DHCP server for a lease that matches the MAC address of the network card

Comment: ... using dhcping utility.

Comment: I only have access to the client machine.