# Where does Slackware's DHCP client store lease information?

Tags: linux, dhcp, slackware

This is a followup to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/64270/distribution-independent-way-of-testing-if-an-interfaces-current-ip-was-obtained).

I eventually got my hands on a Slackware 12.1 machine with a dynamically-assigned IP address. It turns out it uses neither `dhclient` nor `pump` to get the address, it uses `dhcpcd`.

I can't for the life of me find where in the filesystem it stores the lease information. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **dhcpcd** manpage:

```
<ConfigDir>/dhcpcd-<interface>.info
    file in which dhcpcd saves the host information. The word <interface> is actually replaced with the network interface name like eth0 to which dhcpcd is attached.
```

The default **ConfigDir** in Slackware 12 is **/etc/dhcpc**